# Mute string after pull off while tapping

Tags: guitar, guitar-tapping

When playing tapping 2 or more string how to mute string after pull off?

I found hard to play [this particular riff](https://youtu.be/TJfAI2eA5nE?t=54s) and i can't see that he's doing anything to mute the strings after he pulls off, it's like the strings are muting by themselves.

I have no problem with the other strings that don't supposed to sound, but those 
I've hit are left ringing and i can't figure out how to mute them.
Is anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: This video seems to be blocked in the US.

Comment: Yes, it seems so, what is strange because the video is on the band's official channel. I tried to watch other videos with this song via vpn and it seems every video to be blocked in the US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a range of techniques. The most common are:

- damping using fretting hand: use the side of a fretting finger or an unused finger
- damping using the picking hand. If you are tapping, you will have spare fingers available, or the heel of your hand.
- wrap a damper around the neck and strings just above the nut.

I use all of those techniques. The damper is very useful for things like Joe Satriani's Midnight, but generally I use the other two techniques interchangeably, depending on what I'm playing.

Having watched the video a number of times now, I think the solution is partially damping using the edge of the tapping finger - if you watch closely he just touches the adjacent string as he taps - and partially down to the compression and distortion used on the effects: the new tap effectively hides the old note. I'm pretty certain he's not using fret hand muting (which you can do by slightly releasing pressure immediately before the new note)

Comment: Would that unused dinner be vegetarian?  Hot or cold? Could we use an unused finger instead?!  Food for thought... +1

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that a fretting hand holds the chord, that's why i can't use damper or fretting hand to mute, but i think it can be done by the picking hand if hit at an angle to the freatboard and picking finger will mute the previous string.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Good old autocomplete on a small phone screen - I hadn't spotted it.

Comment: Constantine - you can easily do it with the fretting hand, but I'm pretty confident he isn't